# How to replace the image?

Tags: extjs

Below code displays the tree structure.When i click on the image Pic.gif,it has to get replaced by new image.Similarly pic1.gif to new image,pic6.gif to new image.Can you help mw with the code where exactly it fits in this code ????

```
var children = [{
    text: 'family',
    icon: 'pic1.gif',
    children: [{
        text: 'parent1',
        icon: 'pic2.gif',
        children: [{
            icon: 'pic3.gif',
            text: 'children1',
            leaf: true},
        {
            icon: 'pic4.gif',
            text: 'children2',
            leaf: true},
        {
            icon: 'pic5.gif',
            text: 'children3',
            leaf: true}]}],

    },
{
    text: 'Parent2',
    icon: 'pic6.gif',
    children: [{
        icon: 'pic7.gif',
        text: 'children4',
        leaf: true},
    {
        icon: 'pic8.gif',
        text: 'children5',
        leaf: true},
    {
        icon: 'pic9.gif',
        text: "children6",
        leaf: true}]}];
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
        loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader(),
        width: 1000,
        height: 1000,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        root: new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
            expanded: false,
            leaf: false,
            icon: 'pic.gif'

            ,
            text: 'Head',
            children: children
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: are you referring to when the node gets expanded? i.e., when you click on pic1.gif node and it shows the child nodes, you want to swap pic1.gif to something else?

Comment: @Jaitsu: Exactly.I needed the same.

Answer (score 3):

You need to trigger the icon change when the node is expanded using the `beforeexpand` listener:

```
var children = [{
    text: 'family',
    icon: 'pic1.gif',
    listeners: {
       'beforeexpand': function(node) {
           node.setIcon('newImage.gif');
       }
    }
    children: [{
    //...
```

You can repeat that for your other node also.

Comment: I too have a similar Question,
Unfortunately I couldn't see,
beforeexpand event as it is treepanel.
Any Suggestions ?
And on recieved component setIcon('newImage.gif'); is also not available