# How to form a folder structured tree in EXTJS?

Tags: extjs

Can any one help me how to form a folder structured tree in EXTJS.I tried a lot but couldn't swap the images of folders(like pics has to change when children compressed/expanded).I'm very new to EXTJS.It'll be very helpful.

Comment: did you have a look at the examples? what did you try? provide your code and explain where you are stuck...

Comment: @Abdel: I was expecting u here.Thank you.as u said earlier to dump into js fiddle,i did.here's d link 'http://jsfiddle.net/N5nEv/16/'

Comment: I want the folder structured tree to be displayed.Tree is working but i dunno how to make it.Can u look into that link and modify it ?

Comment: sorry, I really don't understand what you mean by "folder structured tree" and you say tree is working?

Comment: @Abdel: here's the link for http://jsfiddle.net/N5nEv/16/

Comment: I mean images has to be displayed in those folders type.That's it.I don't know how to swap/replace an image when expanded/compressed respectively. http://jsfiddle.net/N5nEv/16/

Comment: @Abdel: Hav u looked into that code ?

Comment: I had provided an answer to this question.. did you try it?

Comment: I tried it but image ws unable to swap.The listener for which i had added was neither expanding nor compressing.Can you make it correctly,plzz ?

Comment: I cannot find that question.. do you have the link?

Comment: Here is similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190821/how-to-replace-the-image did you have a look at this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N5nEv/16/

Comment: no. the link to your old question.. since you created a new account.. i cannot find it

Comment: i don't remember it.this is newly created one.Hav u looked at this jsfiddle link ?

Comment: i tried alot to contact u.Bt didn't get to connect u.my eamil ID is jackie.james007@gmail.com

Comment: did you check the above link?.. that should solve your problem as well..

Comment: tried.bt didn't.I think i'm wrongly misplaced that code.Can u make it xactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you will need to set the image when expanding a tree's node:

```
listeners: {
    beforeexpandnode: function(node){
        node.setIcon("your-new-image");
    },
    beforecollapsenode: function(node) {
        node.setIcon("your-default-image");
    }
}
```

The `beforeexpandnode` event listener set the new icon and `beforecollapsenode` set the icon back to your default icon.

Comment: I read that each listener has it's own set of variables that is passed to the function.So,according to this what does this node signify(or what variable to be used ?) have you looked at jsfiddle link ?

Comment: the node is the TreeNode you clicked on!

Comment: Man.. why don't you try or read or try to learn??? put the code in your TreePanel declaration! refer to: http://jsfiddle.net/N5nEv/17/

Comment: @Abdel: I'm trying it.I'll let u know if any doubts further.Don't mind,plzz.

Comment: I tried as u said.But I could see only a first node 'PARENT'.Rest tree is not functioning.Even pic too not changing.